# How do you bootstrap a web app web page and Java classes with endpoints at the same time?

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-rs, wildfly, ear

I've setup a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse to deploy as a EAR in WildFly 15 and I've copy-pasted my custom Java classes and the library files, since I'm not using Maven for this project for simplicity sake. I've of course also copy-pasted the web contents into the folder `webapp`.

My problem is the following:

- I'm trying to launch the web contents (function of a web server) and also have an POST request endpoint active at the same time, but when I launch the web app the welcome page loads index.html but when I try to post it via a button it throws out 404 for the URL, even though it's defined in one of the custom Java classes.

What's funny under JAX-WS Web Services it shows the necessary classes in order for it to function but it simply does not work:
[image: JAX-WS Web Services structure]

Am I missing something here in order to bootstrap it?

My HelloWorldServicePublisher looks like the following:

```
 package main.java.com.projectname.vorlagenwerk;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

//import static org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.MapObject.log;

public class HelloWorldServicePublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, Exception {

        //Settings config=null;
        //config=new Settings();

        //Connection conn = null;
        //Connection jdbcConnection = null;

// postgres adapter
        FreshDB creator = new FreshDB();

        creator.createDB();


        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/vorlagenwerkwebservice_child/HelloWorldServiceImpl", new HelloWorldServiceImpl());
    }
}
```

The endpoint should return the string `test` for now.

Comment: Why the close vote without any comment?..

Comment: "I'm not using Maven for this project for simplicity sake" - this is totally wrong.  You need a build tool for anything except the simplest Java program.

Comment: Fast is not synonymous with correct and simple. You said you copied and pasted a web page, so 'it throws out 404 for the URL, even though it's defined in one of the custom Java classes' may be due to this, but your code is not complete and we cannot answer. Maybe do your things in the right way can be a good start to understand your problem.

Comment: @AndreaTaroni86 it does not throw a 404 for the web page, but rather for the API/Endpoint/whatever you wanna call it. What information do you exactly need additionally?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your requirements.  You want JAX-WS but you also want a web page?  While not impossible you generally don't make SOAP web service calls from a web page.  Would you prefer JAX-**RS** which using JSON to do this?

Comment: @stdunbar the web page should POST a XML and a JSON, of which both get processed, but for now the files get statically loaded when I click the button.

Comment: That's very non-standard.  No wonder you're having an issue.  Let me dig out some code.

Comment: @stdunbar the bounty ends in one day.. I would appreciate very much if you could post an answer ^^